# Rest Assured: how to upload file with resumableChunk Form Data in application through Rest assured API

Tags: api, rest-assured

i want to upload file in system using rest Assured API.

Following are the information i get from Browser Network tab of application .

**Request URL:**
https://ServerURL/api/upload/files/chunk?resumableChunkNumber=1&resumableChunkSize=5242880&resumableCurrentChunkSize=13434&resumableTotalSize=13434&resumableType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&resumableIdentifier=13434-Textxlsx&resumableFilename=Text.xlsx&resumableRelativePath=Text.xlsx&resumableTotalChunks=1

**Form Data**
resumableChunkNumber: 1
resumableChunkSize: 5242880
resumableCurrentChunkSize: 8271
resumableTotalSize: 8271
resumableType: text/plain
resumableIdentifier: 8271-Blanktxt
resumableFilename: Blank.txt
resumableRelativePath: Blank.txt
resumableTotalChunks: 1

Please help me create post method to upload file with resumableChunk.

Thanks in advance